# Deploying FMX Delphi Sydney 10.4.2 to IOS Simulator Error ( xcode 12.5 / IOS 14.5 )

Tags: deployment, ios-simulator, firemonkey, delphi-10.4.2

I tried my first test to deploy a simple FMX app to the Apple world. I have MacBook Pro Intel i5 with MacOS BigSur 11.5.2 installed ( upgraded from Mojave ) and installed xcode from Apple store 12.5 ( supporting IOS 14.5 ) . Deploying to the 64bit macOS itself worked. Now I try to deploy to IOS Simulator but I got error '/Applications/PAServer-21.0.app/Contents/MacOS/db...' unable to create process.
I can't find the full error on delphi side ( not more info in output or build messages ). running the PA server in verbose gives as last command "Applications/PAServer-21.0.app/Contents/MacOS/dbkosx_27_0" - listen.

I'm new to this so unsure if these versions combinations ( MacOS BigSur 11.5.2 / XCode 12.5 / IOS 14.5 ) should work or not. And if not, what combination should work. To test, I installed IOS 13.7 support on Xcode / simulators and devices screen and created a new device. But I don't know to get delphi downloading the SDK for this from the Mac. It's still using IOS 14.5 SDK also for this device.
If I try to start the app directly on the mac , I get an error that seems to hint that it would be a 32bit application ????

I see that build process is using 'dccios32.exe' ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't find the dokwiki is super clear on this, but I'm getting the impression that IOS Simulator support has always been restricted to 32bit ( and so earlier version of xcode / IOS SDK ).
And although it was expected to become supported on 64bit ( since we have 64bit MacOS compiler ), it still isn't ( and will not be ? ) .

I just installed Delphi 11.0 specifically for this to check, and the IOS simulator option has disappeared as platform ! Only IOS64 bit.

To bad there is no clearer info on this..The platform status page https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/PlatformStatus/en/Main_Page does not mention the IOS simulator as a separate platform ( which would make it clearer if the column would be there and had 'not supported' for recent IOS ), because the option is still available as a platform in 10.4.2...

If you are new in this area, and didn't get the history, not obvious to detect all of this.( and still not sure I'm 100% correct on this...)